# Showing the set is not open.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(z) \ge 0\}$, show it is not an open
> set.

In order to show $D$ is not open, I try to show that $D^c$ is open. So by definition, I need to show $\forall w \in D^c, \exists r > 0$ such that $B_r(w) \subseteq D^c$, where $D^c = \{z \in \mathbb{C}, \Re{z} < 0 \}$.

For all $w \in D^c$, let $r = \frac{-\Re(z)}{2} > 0$. Then

\begin{align}
\Re(w) &= - \Re(z) + \Re(z-w) \hspace{1cm}  (1)\\ 
       &>- \Re(z) + \frac{\Re(z)}{2} \hspace{1.75cm}  (2)\\
       &=\frac{-\Re(z)}{2} >0
\end{align}

I'd like to ask, if this proof is correct? And if it is, how do I justify going from (1) to (2)? Thanks.

Comment: But if you prove $D^c$ is open, how does it follow that $D$ is open? By proving $D^c$ is open you only show $D$ is closed, not that it's not open. It does follow that $D$ can't be open, this is because the complex plane is connected. (i.e the only subsets which are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{C}$) But that's a not very trivial fact, and I'm not sure you are supposed to use it for this exercise. It's better to show directly that $D$ doesn't satisfy the definition of an open set.

Comment: Reductio ad absurdum : $D$ is open, then $D^c$ is closed. Try to use some properties of closed sets to find a contradiction (Can you try limits ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving that $D^\complement$ is open only proves that $D$ is closed, but your goal is to prove that $D$ is not open open, not that it is closed.

The set $D$ is not open because, for instance, $0\in D$ but, for any $\varepsilon>0$, if you consider the open disk $B_\varepsilon(0)$, then $-\frac\varepsilon2\in B_\varepsilon(0)$, but $-\frac\varepsilon2\notin D$. Therefore, $B_\varepsilon(0)\not\subset D$.

Comment: I see, so we basically show that a point in $D$ is not an interior point. This is much easier. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't thinking about interior points. I was thinking about the definition of open set: a subset $A$ of $\Bbb C$ is open when, for each $z\in A$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B_\varepsilon(z)\subset A$.